# How to stop swfobject in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, swfobject

How to stop swfobject by using jquery ? Tried `$("#mfplayerobj").stop();` but is is not available for this.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<object width="100%" height="100%" id='mfplayerobj'
            classid=""
            codebase="">
            <param name="SRC" value="/fmplayer/test.swf" />
            <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
         <embed id='mfplayer' wmode="transparent" src="/fmplayer/test.swf" width="100%" height="100%"></embed>
        </object>
```